# error while visualizing the cascade stage features

Tags: opencv, object-detection, cascade, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I have trained a boosted cascade classifier with opencv and i want to visualize the cascade stages features as shown in the tutorial here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/...

The problem is that everytime i run the batch: 
**opencv_visualisation --model=sunmodel.xml --image=sunn.bmp**

where sunn.bmp is actually a positive sample from the training set, and i have also resized it to **24*24** as the defined dimension in the training process.

**I get the following error:** 
*the model is not an haar or lbp feature based model! please select a model that can be visualised by the software*

Although i am using Haar features in the training, I am also using the cascade parameter mode to be: 
**-mode ALL**

Any idea what is happening?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you have this fixed. I had the same error and I was able to get visualisation to run by re-running opencv_traincascade with -numStages turned down to the stage I wanted to visualise. I then used the cascade.xml file that was output.

Like I said i'm not sure if this will work for you however it did work for me.

Turtle

Comment: thanks for the response, i have left that implementation without visualising the features, however i will give your suggestion a go and see how it goes. 

Thank you very much.